# Block changing spam email in Outlook 2010

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook-2010, spam-prevention

How do you setup a junk email filter to block spam in Outlook 2010 where everything about the sender's email address changes except the top-level domain name, e.g. example@example.xyz.  Everything changes except the .xyz part

I get different variations on this theme with different top-level domains, like .click, .link, .science, .webcam, and .xyz. I tried putting a spam filter in Outlook to block the messages by adding:
@*.click
@*.link
@*.science
@*.webcam
@*.xyz

I was hoping that the * character would work as a wildcard to block the changing domain names, but it's not working.  Any ideas?

Comment: It's not possible to block top level domains in the way that you want on the client (outlook) - with the exception of blocking by country code. You have to do this kind of blocking on the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added ".science" in the rules for "with specific words in the senders address" and it worked.

Note: I am using the latest version of Outlook via Office 365 so it may be different but probably worth testing in Outlook 2010

Comment: I created the rule you describe in Outlook 2010 and it works perfectly.  The only problem is that the top-level domain name in the sender's address is always changing, forcing me to update the rule on a daily basis.